# Cascade training for road crack detection

Tags: opencv, detection

I've been working on a cascade using the LBP feature, that will help me detect road crack on pavement pictures taken from a drone. I did a lot of test and different list of pictures, but i have a lot of false positives.

Im asking myself if this method is good for this kind of detection and is there a better method i could use, other than simple threshold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Training LBP or Haar Cascade Classifiers for detecting cracks on the road is in my experience not the best solution as there is no common denominator compared to detecting faces etc. Do you have a proper set of data for training? How many positives are you using? I don't think there are enough features selected and that's why you are getting so many false positives, simply because it cannot distinguish these during the training.

Start out with different thresholds of the road as you mentioned and see if you can distinguish the cracks. Once they are visible enough in contrast to the road you will be able to go from there.

Comment: i only have 150 positive and 200 negative, with threshold i'm able to find all the crack but i also find the brake mark on that road as well. I'll try with enhancing the contrast as you said

Comment: @PatrickVigneault Do you have any progress? I'm doing the analysis of steel surface quality it is more like your image.

Comment: @bygreencn Sorry I forgot this question, well I manage to make a great detection using a dijkstra algorithm on the grey value of pixels to trace a line on a crack. If you want more info, I think I can send you some code